# What is the transactionId in janrain authentication request?

Tags: janrain

What is the transactionId in janrain authentication request? How and where does it get generated? Is it a client or server operation?

https://abc.janraincapture.com/widget/get_result.jsonp?transactionId=***vbkw426dlmlndqn25k2yyk7fu5qrm3vrr005n3ht***&cache=1484090422952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transactionId is a randomly generated string that is created by the Janrain client-side libraries.  It is submitted with the original request.  It is then used by the .jsonp call to retrieve the results of the request.  It is single use - once that transactionId has been "consumed" it can not be used again.

This is largely an "internal" feature of the Janrain authentication widget libraries and is not intended to be used as part of their publicly documented api's.

Comment: I have one more question. If I am required to generate it outside of a browser/client, is it possible to do it? Which js file and function call triggers the generation of this random string?

Comment: It's an minified function that is part of the authentication widget libraries.  If you are Janrain customer then you can most likely file a support ticket and reference this question requesting additional clarification - I'm sure they will hunt me down.  Otherwise, for the sake of security through some obscurity, I am going to defer providing too many more details.

Comment: Cheers for all the help :)